# Uplifting strategies when working with Functors

Tags: haskell

Assume that I have a function

```
foo :: a -> b -> c -> d -> e
foo a b c d = somefn a b c d
```

and some functions that return me `a, b, c and d` repsectively

```
getA :: a
getB :: b
getC :: f c
getD :: d
```

only that the function returning `c` is return a functor with c

now I have call site like

```
callfoo = foo getA getB getC getD
```

obviously that wont work as getC returns a functor of c and not c itself. So the only way seems to be

```
callfoo = (foo getA getB) <$> getC <*> getD
```

Apart from the fact that the *simple* call to `foo` gets lost here the signature changes as well to `callfoo :: f e`.
One way to keep it simple is to `(extract getC)` but this is evil and will get you in a special compartment in Haskell-hell. I know.

**My general question is:**
How do I handle situations where I mostly work with non-functorial values but then suddenly one of the values forces me to uplift all the other values as well?

Comment: `fmap (\c -> foo getA getB c getD) getC`?

Comment: Or the slight variant on that given by using the inline form of fmap: `(\c -> foo getA getB c getD) <$> getC`

Comment: I don't see "any" difference between these three variants. Exists? Or is a merely clean code question?

Comment: Your types in your last example don't add up.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `do` syntax:

```
do
    c <- getC
    return (foo getA getB c getD)
```

If you turn on `ApplicativeDo`, this will use the efficient `fmap` form rather than the potentially inefficient `>>=` and `return` form.

There is a [quasiquoter on Hackage for idiom brackets](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/applicative-quoters-0.1.0.8/docs/Control-Applicative-QQ-Idiom.html) which would let you write

```
[i| foo (pure getA) (pure getB) getC (pure getD) |]
```

Otherwise, there is little sugar available. There are many ways to spell your operation with existing combinators, which generally trade off between being generically applicable in all situations and being compact. Some examples include:

```
flip (foo getA getB) getD <$> getC
(\c -> foo getA getB c getD) <$> getC
foo getA getB <$> getC <*> pure getD
foo <$> pure getA <*> pure getB <*> getC <*> pure getD
```